# force downgrade on the next `yum update`

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

1. I have `microcode_ctl-2.1-16.1.el7_3.x86_64`
2. I have control of the `centos repo`
3. I want the next `yum update` which runs on any machine to automatically downgrade this package to `microcode_ctl-2.1-16.el7.x86_64.rpm`

what should I put in the `updates/x86_64/Packages` to force that downgrade or any other way to force that downgrade, (without issuing an explicit `yum downgrade microcode_ctl`)

Answer (score 0):

Depsolvers based on RPM do not support fine grained directives like "downgrade a [ackage" very well. Rebuilding the package to be downgraded with a newer {EPIOCH,VERSION,RELEASE} and adding to your repository will achieve the same effect as an explicit "downgrade" with yum.